# getting going with Xlwings 0.30.15 on Excel 2019

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I've installed Xlwings 0.30.15 into Excel 2019 and then went to its ribbon and entered the path (L:\refinitiv\python\mb.py) to the UDF Modules and the Interpreter. Data entered was tripled checked as correct.

When I click "import functions" I get a popup cmd window and an Excel window, both containing errors and when I try to use any function from the python field I get a "#NAME" error in excel.

I also have a Refinitiv Excel add-in installed and functioning correctly. This is a COM add-in. I have checked with Refinitiv and there does not appear to be a compatibility issue as they publish articles like "How to integrate Financial Data from Refinitiv Data Platform to Excel with Xlwings" (which didn't address my issue).

The content of the CMD prompt window is:

```
xlwings server running, clsid={4CCCB3D7-7D80-4154-A661-62E0EC20FA00}, event loop on 23316
pythoncom error: Python error invoking COM method.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-           packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 305, in _Invoke_
    return self._invoke_(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 310, in _invoke_
   return S_OK, -1, self._invokeex_(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args, None, None)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 639, in _invokeex_
    return func(*args)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\xlwings\com_server.py", line 231, in Call
    return ToVariant(getattr(obj, method)(*pargs, **kwargs))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\xlwings\udfs.py", line 703, in import_udfs
    module = get_udf_module(module_name, xl_workbook)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\xlwings\udfs.py", line  381, in get_udf_module
   module = import_module(module_name)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'L:\\refinitiv\\python\\mb'
```

Any clues or clarifications would be most welcome and appreciated!

Mark

Comment: Try it without the extension i.e. just `L:\refinitiv\python\mb`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried that but it didn't make any difference - same errors

Comment: The error indicates the file is not found, have you tried referencing from another drive, local drive if L is on a network.

Comment: Yes, I have tried placing the file on C:\ with the same result. Given that the first error at the top of the traceback is from policy.py, I'm wondering if there is some kind of permissions problem either with file access or from within Excell? So far, all I have done is a vannilla install: pip install xlwings, xlwings addin install. I have enabled the addin in Excel. Is there anything else I need to manually set or configure before using xlwings?

Comment: I am also finding that when I enable xlwings that Excel reports an error on startup:  "sorry, Excel can't open two workbooks with the same name at the same time". This is concerning and suggests a misconfiguration.

Comment: If anyone is interested in a PAID consultancy and can help me resolve this on a phone, teams call or similar, please contact me asap.

Comment: You might be trying to load the xlwings addin twice (try removing it from the XLSTART directory and see if the same message occurs) but either way don't expect this to cause an issue. The set shouldn't need any more config that the ribbon settings. You can also try the '_xlwings.conf' Sheet instead, enable by renaming to 'xlwings.conf' and it will take precedence over the ribbon config. I don't know the processes of Xlwings, the policy.py may be normal but you can also raise an issue with the devs and ask these questions.

Comment: Nope that didn't help, but thank you.